# Boo Reference Card?

Tags: boo

I'm looking for a boo syntax sheet/reference card. A quick search on google and on boo's site didn't turn up anything, does anyone know where one is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of an online reference card, but perhaps this might be close enough?

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BOO/Keywords+with+examples

Comment: certainly a good start! thanks!

Comment: How current is this?  I notice it does not include 'macro'.

Comment: The original link is dead. Internet archive to the rescue: http://web.archive.org/web/20150521074325/https://docs.codehaus.org/display/BOO/Keywords+with+examples

Answer (score 1):

This summary is concise and has useful links, although it looks like the author got bored half way through.

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BOO/Language+Summary